# Array of map data renders the map the opposite way

Tags: javascript, tilemap, html-canvas

A while ago by following some tutorials I made a game map array consisting of 0, 1 and 2. I program it the way I want to see it:

```
var mapArray = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];
```

So for example the line `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]` lies on the X axis and I want to see grass `1` horizontally, but when I draw it on the canvas it's being rendered vertically instead. So the *y* and *x* axis are being swapped in place. Why is this so? Here is the rendering code:

```
function render(viewport) {
  context.save();
  context.translate(view.x, view.y);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  var oldPosX = boatPosX;
  var oldPosY = boatPosY;


  for (let i = 0; i < mapArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++) {
      if (mapArray[i][j] == 0) {
        this.sprite.draw(
          background,
          190,
          230,
          26,
          26,
          i * this.sprite.width,
          j * this.sprite.height,
          this.sprite.width,
          this.sprite.height
        );
      }
      if (mapArray[i][j] == 1) {
        this.sprite.draw(
          background,
          30,
          30,
          26,
          26,
          i * this.sprite.width,
          j * this.sprite.height,
          this.sprite.width,
          this.sprite.height
        );

      }
      if (mapArray[i][j] == 2) {
        this.sprite.draw(
          background,
          200,
          20,
          26,
          26,
          i * this.sprite.width,
          j * this.sprite.height,
          this.sprite.width,
          this.sprite.height
        );
      }
    }
  }
  this.ship.drawimage(boat, boatPosX, boatPosY, 50, 50);
  var lineHeight = 16 * 2.286;
  var textWidth = context.measureText(theArray[moveCount].question).width * 3;
  context.textAlign = 'left';
  context.textBaseline = 'top';
  context.font="14px Verdana";
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0 ,0.9)';
  context.fillRect(boatPosX + ship.width / 2, boatPosY - ship.height / 2, textWidth, lineHeight);
  context.fillStyle = 'white';
  context.fillText(theArray[moveCount].question, boatPosX + ship.width / 2, boatPosY - ship.height / 2);

  answerBtn1.innerHTML = theArray[moveCount].answer1;
  answerBtn2.innerHTML = theArray[moveCount].answer2;
  if(isPositionWall(boatPosX, boatPosY)) {
    boatPosX = oldPosY;
    console.log("collision");
  }

  context.restore();

};
```

Comment: Because you swapped `i` and `j` for either drawing or indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the index `i` to read horizontal values and `j` for vertical values, but the way you stored values is reversed. If you had a 2D array (a matrix) it'd work, however you defined an array whose elements are arrays themselves.

When you read `mapArray[0]` you get the array `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` which is the first row of world tiles. Then, `mapArray[1]` will return the second row, and so on. So, `mapArray[i]` returns the *i*-th row of your tilemap, and it means you're using the index `i` to navigate through columns, not rows; though you're using the variable `i` the other way round. Same applies for variable `j`.

To quick fix it, just change the way you read `mapArray`: to access the element in *i*-th row, *j*-th column, you need to write `mapArray[j][i]`.

#### Edit #1

The quick fix is not ideal, since `i` and `j` aren't used to navigate the tilemap only but also to proper render sprites.

Then, you only need to reverse usage of `i` and `j` in loops, where they are used as coordinates of the map array. The new nested loop will look like this:

```
for (let j = 0; j < mapArray.length; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < mapArray[j].length; i++) {
        // draw
    }
}
```

You may also use separate variables to store `arrayMap` sizes, and the code will look even more clear:

```
var W;
var H = mapArray.length;

for (let j = 0; j < H; j++) {
    W = mapArray[j].length;
    for (let i = 0; i < W; i++) {
        // draw
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now, but I have other problem. If I keep the code the way it was before, I can create the array map however I want. But if I swap it to `mapArray[j][i]` like you said, I keep getting `script.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` and the line 113 is this inside the render code I posted OP ` if (mapArray[j][i] == 0) {` Do you have any idea why this could be happening? If it deserves its own question, let me know, I will create another question dedicated to this error.

Comment: So after some debugging I found out that I get this error if my `mapArray` has more members horizontally than vertically. If I have 15 members on each column then I have to have 15 or more rows otherwise I get the error. Can't think of any reason for this happening

Comment: This may be due to spread usage of indexes `i` and `j` for rendering. I edited my answer to include an alternate solution.