# How can I have more values in array on X axis than Y axis in my tilemap?

Tags: javascript, sprites, matrix, html-canvas, spritesheet

Following my old question [Array of map data renders the map the opposite way](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/158988/array-of-map-data-renders-the-map-the-opposite-way) after I got the answer to it and fixed my problem, I got another problem that occurs. If my `mapArray[]` is bigger on X axis than Y axis, I get

> script.js:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

So if my array looks like this, for example:

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
```

I get an error. If I change it to this:

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,],
```

(more values vertically) it works fine. I know that it has to do with my loop condition:

```
for (let i = 0; i < mapArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++) {
```

`j < mapArray[i].length` this is not true if `j` is bigger than `i` length. Makes sense. But if I change the comparison `<` value to `>` I don't get drawn on the canvas anything but the white bg only.

My question: How can I have a big mapArray horizontally so that I could scroll it and have big game world without making it huge on the `y` axis as well?

Code:

```
var mapArray = [
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
];

function render(viewport) {
  context.save();
  if(Math.floor(boatPosX / 36) < 10) {
    context.translate(view.x, view.y);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  var oldPosX = boatPosX;
  var oldPosY = boatPosY;


  for (let i = 0; i < mapArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++) {

      if (mapArray[j][i] == 0) {
        this.sprite.draw(
          background,
          190,
          230,
          26,
          26,
          i * this.sprite.width,
          j * this.sprite.height,
          this.sprite.width,
          this.sprite.height
        );
      }
      if (mapArray[j][i] == 1) {
        this.sprite.draw(
          background,
          30,
          30,
          26,
          26,
          i * this.sprite.width,
          j * this.sprite.height,
          this.sprite.width,
          this.sprite.height
        );

      }
      if (mapArray[j][i] == 2) {
        this.sprite.draw(
          background,
          200,
          20,
          26,
          26,
          i * this.sprite.width,
          j * this.sprite.height,
          this.sprite.width,
          this.sprite.height
        );
      }
    }
  }
  this.ship.drawimage(boat, boatPosX, boatPosY, 50, 50);

  if(isPositionWall(boatPosX + 36, boatPosY)) {
    //boatPosX = oldPosY;
    console.log("collision");
  }
  context.restore();

};
```

I know what's causing the problem (the loop) but not sure how to fix it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your for loop, you need to index `mapArray` first by `i`, and then by `j`. You are doing this correctly in the loop condition, but inside the loop you use the indices in the wrong order.

So if-statements like these:

```
if (mapArray[j][i] == 0)
```

need to be changed to

```
if (mapArray[i][j] == 0)
```

Comment: But then my array is being rendered in the opposite way. Read my old question I have linked in OP. That was the reason to switch `i` `j` in places. So how should I approach this? Just deal with it being the opposite way? Because now I want to see the array being rendered the way it is coded in the file, f.e `[0, 1, 0]` meaning water on the left and right sides and ground in the middle. Not water on top and bottom.

Comment: Then you'll also need to simply swap the indices when you calculate positions for the tiles, i.e. `i * this.sprite.width` needs to become `j * this.sprite.width`. You are creating confusion for yourself by naming the indices `i` and `j`. It would be much clearer for you if you named them properly, `i` being `y` and `j` being `x`.